# Solaris how to access smb:/// from terminal?

Tags: samba, solaris

I installed solaris from its file browser i can access computers in my windows network with:

```
smb:///
```

however I cannot find how to access it from terminal.

```
ls smb:///
smb:///: No such file or directory
ls vol
dev dsk rdsk rmt
ls mnt
nothign here...
```

can anyone help please? i want to access this smb from terminal...
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The terminal doesn't know about URIs (which is what smb:/// is), only files and directories and such.

You will have to mount the remote share into the local filesystem - not sure how you'd do that in solaris off hand, but on Linux it's with the `mount.cifs` program, or on FreeBSD it's `mount_smbfs`

The other option is to use the `smbclient` command line tool to interact with a CIFS share.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Solaris 10 or older, there is a commercial product named sharity that provides CIFS mounts: http://www.obdev.at/products/sharity-light/index.html

With OpenSolaris and newer (Solaris 11 Express), cifs support is included: http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+on/2008021301

Also:

```
man mount_smbfs
```